# Excel VBA Match Function ignoring updated Sort

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Ok, so I have a list of items that's typically sorted by rarity, but for one specific action I need it to be sorted so that a match function works on it, so I have it set up to sort it for the match function, then resort it back. The match function, however, is pulling up what row it was in before the sort, however. Does anyone know how this might be fixed? Code below (I'm including the bulky sort codes):

```
'Sort for Match Function
Sheets("Item List").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("L2:U2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "L2:L300"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("L1:U300")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


Dim x As Integer
x = Application.Match(BuyItem.Value, Range("TraderItems"))
MsgBox (x)


'Sort back to Rarity
Sheets("Item List").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("L2:U2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "R2:R300"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("L1:U300")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Replace `TraderItems` with the actual range.

Comment: what is `Range("TraderItems"))` ? do you have a named range "TraderItems" ? where do you set it up ?

Comment: Also, if you have calculation off try putting a force calculate range in there after the sort...

Comment: `Range("TraderItems")` is the defined range of `Sheets("Item List").Range(L2, L300)`. (It extends beyond what's necessary)

Alright, I'll try replacing the name with the actual range stuff

Comment: Alright, that didn't help, replacing `Range("TraderItems")` with `Sheets("Item List").Range("L2", "L300")` netted the same thing, giving me the row it was in before

Comment: Range("L2", "L300") = L2 & L300. Use Range("L2:L300") instead

Comment: @Absinthe No, this format has been working fine for me for this whole project, and it's pulling up numbers that are in between those two numbers, it's just not pulling up the one it should be after the sort

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Match function.  So I couldn't get that part to work.  And I was confused by all the "select" code in your original sub.  So I simply copied the range into an array array, sorted the range, bypassed the Match command because I don't know values you are using, and then copied the original numbers back into the range.

I hope this helps

```
Sub tester()

Dim Arr() As Variant, x As Integer, arr2Rng As Range
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Activate

    Arr = Range("L1:U300")
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Range("L1:U300").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "L2:L300"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("L1:U300")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(BuyItem.Value, Range("TraderItems"))
    MsgBox (x)


    Range("L1").Select
    Set arr2Rng = Range("L1")
    arr2Rng.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr


    End Sub
```